# Search image text box popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have a search image link that on click open a text box popup, after entering some text in  search box and clicking the button again it closes the pop up, on the second event i need the that image to do post back, How i can do that, 
I am pasting the code here

```
<div class="searchBox align_right">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);">Search</a>
   <div style="display: none;" class="searchPopup">

     <input type="text" name="s" id="searchText"  
           onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) searchRESLT();" />

     <input type="button" onclick="searchRESLT();" />

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what exactly is your problem? it the searchRESLT function not triggering if you re-click the search link or doesnt it work at all? means does it work on hitting your key or clicking on the button? any errors in the console?

Comment: Search work on pressing enter key, but basically i need to add two events on my image i.e. at first it should popup a text box and after that on click this image should perform serach.
If i press enter after adding fields in text box it is working fine

Comment: here is the jquery code for popup
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.searchBox a').click(function(){
  jQuery(".searchPopup").slideToggle('fast');
 });
});      
How i can edit it to add another event of post back

Comment: you can add a class to the popup box like 'open' in your popup open code. after that check if your a tag has the class - if not open the box like you do at the moment. if it has the class call your searchRESLT function, close the popup and remove the open class

Comment: Ok i have added some code and this thing is working, But now their isanother issue, I have to click the search image twice to open a pop up text box.I am pasting the code here

Comment: and where is the code?